# Android app to take and text picture every hour

Tags: android, camera

I would like to use my old phone to take a picture and text it to me every hour. The app must work on Android 5.1, automatically take a picture with flash every hour, and send it via MMS (I will not have wifi or data available). Thank you!

Comment: You could probably use Tasker for that